# How to fix LaTeX errors with "I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Manuscript.aux"?

Tags: errors, bibitem

When I run LaTeX on my file "manuscript.tex", where I don't call any bibliography file like "manuscript.bib" but rather include bibliography items within the source document itself using "\begin{thebibliography}{99} ............. \end{thebibliography}", I get a good PDF file, but I get these error messages every time I compile with LaTeX:

"This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: Manuscript.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Manuscript.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Manuscript.aux
(There were 2 error messages)"

Kindly help me on how to fix these 2 error messages?

Thanks a lot - Sundar

Comment: don't use texify to compile, use pdflatex directly (the messages are harmless, they simply tell you that texify run bibtex without need).

Answer (score -1):

The error seems to be due to the fact that I was not using any *.bib file for my paper and the bibliography is provided at the end of the main document itself using \begin{bibliography} ...... \end{bibliography} environment..

I was following the sample latex template given by the control journal.. I agree that *.bib is easier to use and manage bibitems.. Thank you.